# Using Chromium Cookies in a perl script

Tags: perl, cookies, sqlite, chromium

I'm trying to write a perl script to connect to a website and am having issues with storing the cookies that I'm grabbing out of the Chromium SQLite database.  Here's the relevant code snippet:

```
use HTTP::Cookies;
use Data::Dumper;
use feature 'say';
use DBI;

my $cookie_jar = HTTP::Cookies->new();
my $dbh = DBI->connect("dbi:SQLite:dbname=/home/{user}/.config/chromium/Default/Cookies",
   "", "");
my $sth = $dbh->prepare("select * from cookies where host_key='{domain}'");
$sth->execute();
my $rows;
while ($rows = $sth->fetch()) {
    say Dumper($rows);
    $cookie_jar->set_cookie(@$rows[0],
                            @$rows[1],
                            @$rows[2],
                            @$rows[3],
                            @$rows[4],
                            @$rows[5],
                            @$rows[6],
                            @$rows[7],
                            @$rows[8],
                            @$rows[9]);
    say Dumper($cookie_jar);

}

$sth->finish();
$dbh->disconnect();

say Dumper($cookie_jar);
```

I scrubbed my username and domain but the "say Dumper($rows)" statement is returning exactly the cookie information that I'm expecting.  Thus, I know my SQLite database access is working.  The "say Dumper($cookie_jar)" both inside and outside the while loop is returning an empty cookie_jar.  I've just started playing around with perl so is there something I'm missing when it comes to setting data?

Answer (score 1):

I found that there are no standard cookie values or a standard order to store them.  Fields 0-9 in Chromium cookies do not map to fields 0-9 in HTTP::Cookies.  It seems the set_cookie method was failing because of weird values but not being verbose about its errors.  I realized that the better way to approach it was to use hashrefs for the rows so I'd have more readable code:

```
# set_cookie($version, $key, $val, $path, $domain,
#             $port, $path_spec, $secure, $maxage, $discard, \%rest )

while ($rows = $sth->fetchrow_hashref()) {
    $cookie_jar->set_cookie(0,
                            $rows->{name},
                            $rows->{value},
                            $rows->{path},
                            $rows->{host_key},
                            443,
                            0,
                            $rows->{secure},
                            1000000,
                            0);
    say Dumper($cookie_jar);

}
```

I've added the set_cookie values in comments to make the method more obvious for other people adapting this to their own purposes.

Comment: Or massage the select statement to give you columns that match the expected params for set_cookie: `"select 0, name, value, path, host_key, null, null, secure, 600 from cookies"` then `$cookie_jar->set_cookie(@$rows);`

Answer (score -1):

When accessing elements in an array reference such as $rows use the arrow operator. In your case change: `@$rows[0]`
to: `$rows->[0]`
for each element.

Comment: This does not seem to be the central problem of this script, so this isn't really an answer. (as an aside, `$$arr[0]` and `$arr->[0]` are totally equivalent. You forgot to mention the obvious solution, the array slice `@$arr[0 .. 9]`)

Comment: I tried all those access methods and, while it's incredibly handy to know alternative ways to reference an array (especially @$arr[0 .. 9]), none of them solved the persistence issue.